# Update multiple rows using WHERE IN where using one MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, where-clause, where-in

I have a one query for select ids from table and another query for update the table values. These are the queries used.

for select ids

`select id from table_1 where orderId = 41 AND status = 1`

for update

`UPDATE table_1 SET orderId  = '17' WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,.....,n);`

This two queries working properly. But when try to this code its not working. I want to update orderId  update 41 to 17 in all the records selected

`UPDATE table_1 SET orderId  = '17' WHERE id IN (select id from table_1 where orderId  = 41 AND status = 1 );`

This query is returns error. Any suggestion to correct this error.
Thank You

Comment: Your queries should not work because `order-id` is an invalid identifier.  Please include the error you are getting.

Comment: i edited for add this question.i used order_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that MySQL does not allow you to use the same table in subqueries in an `update` or `delete`.  I think you can simplify the logic, so the subquery is not needed.

Why not just use this?

```
UPDATE table_1
    SET order_id = '17'
    WHERE order_id = 41 AND status = 1;
```

Note:  If `order_id` is a number, use `17` not `'17'` -- don't mix data types.

This assumes that `id` is unique.

Alternatively, if you really need list of ids, you can also use a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE table_1 t1 JOIN
       (SELECT tt1.*
        FROM table_1 tt1
        WHERE tt1.order_id = 41 AND tt1.status = 1
       ) tt1
       ON tt1.id = t1.id
    SET t1.order_id = 17;
```